# Poedit translations are not translated when using angular ng-include

Tags: poedit, angularjs-ng-include

I want to have my text translated and I am using poedit to translate my text.
I am working in ZF2.

I do have my translation file (created with poedit) in place. And that is working.
For example: in this view example the "Sign in" is translated.

```
(1) <a href="#">{{'Sign in' | trans}}</a>
```

No I want to add the login view with ng-include, like this:

```
(2) <div ng-include="'/account/login'"></div>
```

That works fine too, my login view is there.

But: none of the translations do work in this view. In the login view, this:

```
(3) <span>{{ 'Password' | trans }}</span>
```

is not translated. If I add that (3) code however directly after (1), the translation works.

My Question is: how can I ensure that the translations do work when I use a ng-include to add other views?

Hope my question makes sense and that someone knows what to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this.. I think one of the solution is for example:

```html
<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
   <span>{{ Password }}</span>
</div>
```

and then on your LoginCtrl should look like this:

```js
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate) {
  // expose translation via `$translate` service
  $translate('Password').then(function (password) {
    $scope.Password = password;
  });
}]);
```

you may go to this article for more info http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service#using-$translate-service_things-to-keep-in-mind